# Teachings of Ravana

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana, lakshmana

I've heard that at the time of Ravana's death, Lord Rama sent his younger brother Lakshmana to take guidance from him on life.

I have read several versions of it; one of them is [this](http://daily.bhaskar.com/news/JM-3-shocking-things-raavan-told-lord-ramas-brother-lakshman-before-dying-4467208-PHO.html). But not sure what really are those instructions from Ravana. Did this really happen? Can someone state those Ravana's teachings with authentic source(s)?

Comment: You might be interested in this essay/article: [Three Hundred Ramayanas](http://www.openthemagazine.com/article/art-culture/three-hundred-ramayanas)